# Robot Framework Parameterizing using yaml file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, yaml, robotframework, pyyaml

Hi can anybody help me parameterize the string word so it will fetch from my yaml. I tried to run however I'm getting an error it shows failed: Using YAML variable files requires PyYAML module to be installed. Typically you can install it by running `pip install pyyaml`. but I already install pyyaml on my local machine. your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much

Expected Result: ${String} parameter should get the value from my robot.yaml (Ralph) value

VS Terminal Screenshot:

[image]

.robot screenshot

[image]

robot.yaml file screenshot:
[image]

CMD Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `robot.yaml` define PYTHONPATH like this:

```
PYTHONPATH:
  - .
  - string: "RALPH"
```

Make sure you have installed `PyYAML`, then include `robot.yaml` and `collections` library in the robot file:

```
Variables         path_to_file/robot.yaml

Library           Collections
```

After this you can extract string value inside the test like this:

```
${value} =     pop from dictionary     ${PYTHONPATH[1]}     string
log to console   ${value}
```

This will print:

```
RALPH
```

Second item in PYTHONPATH list is a dictionary, so you first need to access `${PYTHONPATH[1]}` and then pop the needed key (in your case `string`) in order to return its value.